# How to restrict a Service Principle access to specific folder in ADLS Gen2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to configure Power BI connectivity to ADLS Gen2 using Service Principle.  I would like to restrict access to a specific folder (and sub folders underneath).

It looks like the Service Principle needs to be added to either 'Data Reader' or 'Data Contributor' RBAC role at the container level. This automatically grants the access to entire folders under the container root.

How can I restrict the Service Principle access to specific folder level?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict the Service Principle access to the specific folder level, we can use [Access Control List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#access-control-lists-on-files-and-directories) to implement it. The ACL use **Read**, **Write**, and **Execute** to control access.
[image]

Regarding how to use these permissions to control access, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#common-scenarios-related-to-permissions). 
For example, if we want to read the file in one folder, we need to give the security principal `Execute` permissions to the container, and to each folder in the hierarchy of folders that lead to the file and `Read` permissions to the file by using [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-explorer#managing-access).

However, please note that we can't use access control lists to provide a level of access that is lower than a level granted by an Azure RABC  role assignment. For example, if you assign the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to a service principal, then you can't use access control lists to prevent that service principal from writing to a directory. So I suggest you remove the service principal Azure RABC  role assignment when you use the ACL to control access.

Comment: Thanks! Service Principle access works. However for user, when I remove the RBAC role assignment, Azure Storage Explorer is not listing the folder with ACL setup unless I grant the user container root level Read and Execute access.  This setup is listing all folders under the root even though user can not read those folders. Any thoughts?